# Why us ROKU TV connecting to my PC through my router?

Tags: firewall

I noticed this connections "HisenseRokuTV-SXP.lan" in my `arp` list of connections. That seems pretty sketchy, as even though I'm using the TV as a monitor through HDMI, they are only connected through my router.

I checked my GLi.net router for a button to isolate APs, like my DD-WRT router has, but didnt find one (so I just blocked it for now). I can route the TV through my DD-WRT router for that, but I feel like my firewall shouldn't have allowed that (maybe it did when it was disabled). So how should I set my firewall to block such a connection? I'm using UFW on Kubuntu 22.04, and have incoming blocked and forwarding allowed (for VMs). I only have two rules in iptables to allow established connections (not sure if there are better rules for this).

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: To be frank, what are you even talking about? What do you even mean by "seems pretty sketchy"? Isn't it perfectly normal to see a device in your LAN showing up on another's arp list? If you just want to use it as a monitor, why do you even hook it to your home network (wiredly or wirelessly)?

Comment: If you want the  TV to be able to reach Internet but not your other LAN devices, your switch (or the "switch part" of your home router) needs to be able to filter (e.g. based on the in and/or out switch port). iptables does not work on the switch part of it. (Certainly though you can avoid having prefix route on the TV and filter on the `FORWARD` chain, like using `/32` / `255.255.255.255` on it, if that sounds secure enough to you.)

Comment: @TomYan I never said I just want to use it as a monitor.. idk, is that normal to see every device on a network with arp, I thought I needed to scan with nmap for that? I say sketchy because of the reports of smart TV's phoning home about what youre doing.. so yeah, i'm sketched out on smart tvs in general.. I probably need to put it on a guest network, but want to keep it on wired not wireless.. I guess I need firewall rules for isolation that way.

Comment: @TomYan Could you show a more detailed example? Some routers do have iptables.. and Im setting up pfsense in a VM, and possible moving it to a hardware device.

Comment: No. As long as either host ever tried to reach the other (a simple ping or whatever), they will be on each other's ARP list. ARP is basically how you get IP to work over Ethernet (or WiFi). And the typical way to protect a host from another within a LAN is to have firewall on the host *itself*, since you can hardly find a home router that its switch part or any unmanaged switch that is able to filter. While you can avoid "defining a LAN" on a "potentially malicious" host, you can't guarantee that it won't add the required direct route to bypass your "forced IP forwarding" measure.

Comment: Before you try to be obsessed with security (or even just get to use or learn iptables / pfsense / blah blah blah), you better get to know how IP/Ethernet works first (like how you can reach a host within a LAN / broadcast domain by either involving and not involving a gateway / nexthop / the router part of your router / IP forwarding), and what's the role of a switch and a gateway/router respectively, and why am I keep saying things like "switch / router part of your home router".

Comment: iptables only matters on traffics that are IP-forwarded by a host (A) / router, and a host (B) don't even need that to reach another host (C) within a LAN / broadcast domain (neither do they typically do that).

Comment: hmm, interesting.. so the Roku TV must have tried to nmap the network or something.. DD-WRT has firewall, but it's been buggy in my experience.. I have a firewall on the host and all guests. So I can specifically block this address, but I was looking for a way to block all nmapping/pings. I guess that is icmp, so it gets through the 'block all incoming' in UFW somehow.. I thought maybe through the iptables rule I mentioned above (related/established) if it had connected once when the firewall was down to maybe be 'established'.

Comment: @TomYan "iptables only matters on traffics that are IP-forwarded".. I thought all traffic to and from the host is IP directed.. that is my understanding of how a firewall works.. first on IP filters then on port and protocol filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137207/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-alchemy).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tom Yan, I was reminded that ARP is the macid to IP resolution, so the Roku TV was probable scanning all macids present looking for connectable devices. I'm not sure if it was given my host's IP address.

There seems to be a way to block macid scanning: https://superuser.com/questions/916221/prevent-traffic-to-mac-address-using-ebtables

If it wasn't allowed to connect to my computer via an IP address, it seems less concerning. What are the capabilities of connecting by macid, besides asking for the IP address for 'real' data transfer?

Comment: FWIW, ebtables (or nft bridge table) only works on the virtual bridges, not the physical switch part of your home router. If you really need L2 filtering (port-based or ethernet address based, doesn't matter), you need the switch part itself to have the capabilities / firewall. (So it doesn't matter if your router is xWRT/Linux based or whether its firmware has ebtables / nft).

Comment: Take something like RPi (or actually any PC) as an example. Say it has three interfaces and two of them are bridged together to form the "LAN", then you can use ebtables to filter traffics go back and forth the two interfaces / bridge ports. But if it has only two interfaces and the LAN interface is connected to a switch, you can't filter what goes back and forth the other switch ports on that switch. (The latter case is pretty much what your home router is. Certainly there can be exceptions available on the market though.)

Comment: Also IP isn't really how the switch determine which switch port / host specific traffics should go to. Ethernet address (macid in your word) is. What IP does is more of telling the host the traffics has reached whether these traffics's final destination is this host, and when it is not, IP forwarding kicks in (which is filtered by the FORWARD chain in iptables). You can force a LAN host to send traffics for another one *via* the router, but as I said, if the host is malicious, it can do it the other way behind the scene. ARP is more of *IP to Ethernet address* resolution instead.